# xslt transform structured data using nested templates - split and copy attributes as substrings

Tags: xslt

I have XML file with mixed data, some of them have to be just copied but some of them have to be splited and copied based on separators using xslt v 1.0

**Input is like this one:**

```
<class id=1>
  <teacher id=100>
    Some Teacher
  </teacher>
  <pupils>
    101,boy,John;102,girl,Anna;103,boy,Tom
  </pupils>
</class>
```

**And I have to transform it to this format:**

```
<class id=1>
  <teacher id=100>
    Some Teacher
  </teacher>
  <pupil id=101>
    <gender id="boy">
      <name>
        John
      </name>
    </gender>
  </pupil>
  <pupil id=102>
    <gender id="girl">
      <name>
        Anna
      </name>
    </gender>
  </pupil>
  <pupil id=103>
    <gender id="boy">
      <name>
        Tom
      </name>
    </gender>
  </pupil>
</class>
```

Many thanks in advance how to hadle this.

Comment: The input you show us is not well-formed XML. Attribute values must be quoted. Likewise for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pupils">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <pupil id="{substring-before($token, ',')}">
                <gender id="{substring-before(substring-after($token, ','), ',')}">
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($token, ','), ',')" />
                </name>
                </gender>
                </pupil>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, it is great, please, if I would like to do more with the **teacher**  or any other things (outside template tokenize) how do I use it with "/"

Comment: Add a template matching `teacher` (or any other node you want to process differently). Nodes that are not matched by a more specific template will be processed by the generic *identity transform* template - i.e. copied.

Comment: I see, and I have multiple class-es so now I have to yet use for-each, where to put it inside template or outside or in template class?

Comment: If you have multiple classes, you must also have a higher-level root element enclosing them. This structure will also be automatically copied for you by the *identity transform* template.